# Space on sides of an absolute positioned div

Tags: html, css, css-position

I want to add a space of `10px` on both sides of the `#in` div, like this:

[image]

I have this code - **[live demo](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/bLqan)**:

html

```
<div id="out">
  <div id="in"></div>
</div>
```

css

```css
#out {
  width: 700px;
  height: 40px;
  background: lightblue;
  position: relative;
}

#in {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 20px;
  top: 10px;
  background: white;
  margin: 0 10px;
}
```

Comment: I see the image, but still I have a hard time understanding what you mean. What do you mean "push both side 10 px the #in div"?

Comment: Your approach seems kind of wrong. Please explain what is your final goal. Are you just trying to draw a blue outlined rectablge that has some space at the right and the bottom? Or are the divs going to receive some content (text, images, etc)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No `calc()`, No `box-sizing`. Since the element is positioned `absolute`ly you could set its `left`/`right` offset properties to `10px` instead of specifying an explicit `width` and `margin`s on its sides:

**[Example Here](http://jsbin.com/suxor/1/edit)**

```css
#in {
  position: absolute;
  height: 20px;
  top: 10px;
  left: 10px;
  right: 10px;
  background: white;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to use css [calc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/calc) rule in order to count 100% width - the margin size:

```
#in {
  width: calc(100% - 20px);
}
```

Hope this helps

Comment: -1 : alas, calc is only compliant with the latest Android version, meaning you're too much on the bleeding edge. http://caniuse.com/#feat=calc

Comment: @emmanuel I withdraw my comment since the element is positioned absolutely.

Answer (score 1):

**Solution 1: Just some padding**

You can greatly simplify the CSS:

Just specify the size for the outer div. `box-sizing: border-box` is added to prevent the padding from influencing the width of the div.

```
#out {
  width: 700px;
  padding: 10px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background: lightblue;
}
```

No positioning needed for the other div. Just give it a height, and it will automatically strech the other div:

```
#in {
  height: 20px;
  background: white;
}
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/yICdF

**Solution 2: Use a border**

If your goal is to get a blue border, you don't need two divs at all. What about this one:

```
#out {
  width: 700px;
}
#in {
  height: 20px;
  border: 10px solid lightblue;
}
```

Of course you don't need two divs in this case. Just remove #out altogether and move the `width` property to #in.

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/icHjD